# Is Inheritance considered safe for view models

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

I have some create and edit view models with common properties. I have read online that it's evil to use inheritance for view models. So, I would like to learn is it safe to have these type of view models.

```
public class CustomerVM
{
   public int CustomerId {get;set;}
   public string Name { get; set;}
}

public class CustomerCreateVM : CustomerVM
{
   public dictionary<string,string> ModelCustomers { get; set;}
}

public class CustomerEditVM : CustomerVM
{
   public List<Orders> OrdersList {get;set;}
}
```

CustomerVM is not used in the application, it is only used to store common properties.

Comment: As long as the view model has a well-defined scope and responsibility, I don't have a problem with it (and no technical limits come to mind). However, you could get a dozen different answers to this question.

Comment: Yes, I tried searching online for this. Posts that said its not appropriate were suggesting composition over inheritance. But I don't see how to use composition here and would like to know about the real problem with inheritance.

Comment: There is no silver bullet for this kind of stuff. Usually all my viewmodel inherit from NotificationObject - from Prism framework. I sometime create base view model for commonalities but really rare and with care. I like each ViewModel as independent as possible

Comment: I dont have an issue with it as long as the properties as used the same way across the views.

Comment: Please don't down vote or close. I know there are threads on this topic but they didn't explain why composition is preferred. I just want to confirm if I am doing right way.

Comment: @Sundeep, if they do close it's because such topics are more welcome in the http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ Forum. You would gear a better reaction there.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Appreciated.

Comment: @DaveA, I will consider it for next code post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Argument For:**

"Best Practice" philosophy is moving more and more toward "Fat Models". So Model-Driven design is at a premium. Thus having permutations and abstractions are desirable

**Argument Against:**

As Models are really for passing data to Views, simplicity is best. This plays to the "Controller-Dominated Logic" thought.

**Summary:**
Definitely not evil.

Not even bad. Recommended or not depending on whether you strive for "Fat" sophisticated Models/ "Skinny" Controller or Simple (more to point non-complex) Models for data handling.

I personally steer toward Simplicity for Models. But I've seen enough riddled Controllers to appreciate the other side.

Answer (score 0):

AS the saying goes "Favor Composition over Inheritance".  It would be better to have CustomerVM a property on CustomerEdit than to use inheritance in this way.  In your simple  case you posted I don't think it would matter too much but as the system grows if you become accustomed to using inheritance things can start getting ugly as the models grow in complexity and the depth of the hierarchy increases.

Comment: Reason I was not comfortable with composition is the properties which are directly related to the object will be something like objCustomerVM.CustomerCreateVM.ModelCustomers but with inheritance it will be objCustomerCreateVM.ModelCustomers.